# How can I parse the value to previous activity by using back icon on action bar (android studio)

Tags: android

At first, when a user login to the system, the system will get the user id from the real-time database of Firebase. Then, when the user clicks the profile button, that user id will parse to the profile activity for getting the user's information. But then, when the user clicks the back button on action bar to go back to the previous activity, it appears an error. How can I solve this question?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve? If you don't want to show again any activity use finish method on the activity.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you clearly .
firebase variable is static so you can access it from any activity. what you are lookign for is parsing the user id from the firebase static variable instead of trying to parse it from the profile activity.

Comment: It's helpful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: does that answer your question ?